# Create one file (txt) from mulitple files in dir keeping the name of each in cmd

Tags: cmd

I am using the following to create one file.txt that contains all of the other files(.sql) contents stored in one dir:

```
for %f inv(*.sql) do type "%f" >> file.txt
```

Question: How do I add the filename from each .sql file above each extraction saved to file.txt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just echo another line containing the filename to the collection file. Is there something I am missing?

```
for %f in (*.sql) do echo === "%~f" >>file.txt & type "%f" >>file.txt
```

If you put this into a .bat script, the percent characters must be doubled. It is somewhat more readable on multiple lines.

```
for %%f in (*.sql) do (
    echo === "%%~f" >>file.txt
    type "%%f" >>file.txt
)
```